# 二つのデータフレームの値の違いを一覧で表示してくれる R関数はありますか？

Tags: r

Linuxで言うところの diff関数のようなものを探しています。データフレーム1 とデータフレーム2 は同じデータ構造ですが、一部の値が異なります。この異なる場所を R で特定したいと思います。良い関数/パッケージがあれば紹介して下さい。

Comment: [この回答](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171426/14578930#14578930)が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。教えて頂いたパッケージで課題を解決することができました。